# Google maps API cusom icon (not image)

Tags: html, google-maps, icons

I am using Google maps API. However, since I have very many icons, I am trying them to use with a mapping technology. Therefore I need to add an icon as a div instead of img. Is there a way to append icon to google maps as a ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Put your image in a div and then in version 2 use **GMap2.fromDivPixelToLatLng (or fromContainerPixelToLatLng)**  method for geopositioning **or in v3 fromDivPixelToLatLng (or fromContainerPixelToLatLng)** from MapCanvasProjection class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but V3 allows you to use sprite images via the **origin** property on [MarkerImage](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage). I'm not familiar with V2, but it may have a similar feature.